# Prove there is a single function which is able to be developed to Power series around $x_0 = 0$

Tags: power-series

I have given:
$$f''(x) - 2f'(x) + f(x) = 0$$
$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f'(0) = 1$$
$$find::---- f(x)=?$$.

I wanted to try it by assuming that the series $$f\left(x\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n\cdot x^n$$ is a solution.
But I got stuck here.
I thought maybe using Taylor expansion and find something, but I dont know if it can help me...

Is my idea correct of what I am trying?
I got $f(x)$, I need to derivative it, I will get $f'(x)$ and then again: $f''(x)$.
But the problem I will get this if I use given values:
$$\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n\cdot x^n\:-\:2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:a_n\cdot n\cdot x^{n-1}+\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:a_n\cdot n\left(n-1\right)\cdot x^{n-2}$$
But it wont help me...
Also using the other given values wont help me.. How should I start answer this question? What am I supposed to think when I see this question?

EDIT:
Please help someone, I reached that point:
$$a_n=2a_{n+1}\left(n+1\right)-a_{n+2}\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)$$
With $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$
But I am stuck here.. Someone here tried to help me, but I cant reach that function, we have not learned ODE yet.

Comment: Equate the coefficients of $x^n$ on both sides. Be careful with boundary conditions.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to find in this problem.

Comment: @copper.hat what are you talking about? I dont understand :\ please explain.

Comment: @MattE. I am trying to find the function f(x), sorry for not explaining it very good.

Comment: You need to figure out $a_0,a_1,...$. For example if $a x^2 + b x = x^2 + 3x$ for all $x$ then I know that $a=1, b=3$.

Comment: @copper.hat yea I thought I had to find the recursion formula for $a_n$, but the question is, How to do it... since I need to use some information for it, but I cant eq power series.
If I put $x=0$ on all series, I will just receive 0. which is problematic.

Comment: @copper.hat
Please help now,  I updated the question, how do I continue from here?

Comment: I have not checked your arithmetic, but that it what I would have expected, You would need to solve the difference equation to get an expression for $a_n$ which, base on the accepted answer, would be $a_n = {1 \over (n-1)!}$ for $n >1$.

Comment: I have to use ODE for it? since we really have not learned it :\
How am I supposed to get this? I really cant understand, also the function with $e$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is given by finding the general solution, using characteristic equation of the ODE which leads to the general solution f(x)= a$e^{x}+bxe^{x}$,Setting f(0)=0 we get a=0 and setting f '(0)=1 we get b+b.o=1 hence b=1. So the function you are seeking is f(x)=$xe^{x}$ which is x($\sum_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$) in power series!

Comment: Hi, how did you think of such a thing? how did you think I need to reach that f(x)? I dont know what is ODE, I have never learned that thing, isn't there any way with power series? since this is the subject we learn.

Comment: ODE we will learn soon, we have not learned it yet:\

Comment: Hi, I reached that point:
$a_n=2a_{n+1}\left(n+1\right)-a_{n+2}\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)$
How do I reach your f(x)?